# Sort directories in ascending order of number (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, sorting, directory, numbers

I would like to sort directories in ascending order of number (Python 3.7).

The following is my code:

```
import glob
filenames = glob.glob('/A/**_B/C/D.csv')
```

I try to get all 'D.csv' files' directories and put it in filenames. But It is not ordered in number.

For example;

- filename[0] gives /A/20040226_B/C/D.csv
- filename[1] gives /A/20040505_B/C/D.csv
- filename[2] gives /A/20040703_B/C/D.csv
- ...

I would like to make it like:

- filename[0] gives /A/20040226_B/C/D.csv
- filename[1] gives /A/20040227_B/C/D.csv
- filename[2] gives /A/20040228_B/C/D.csv
- filename[3] gives /A/20040301_B/C/D.csv
- ...

I tried to use

```
filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda x:float(re.findall("(\d+)",x)[0]))
```

or just

```
filenames = sorted(filenames)
```

But it does not work. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I just added a data structure just like you described to my system and executed your code in python 3.6 AND python 3.7 and it worked just fine in both python versions with `sorted(filenames)`. Do you get any other feedback from your python console?

Comment: Actually the directory is '/A/**_Nest_4/C/D.csv'. I used A, B C and D for simplicity

Comment: Yes. it works now. Thank you very much. I don't know why it did not work